# Storing, parsing and calling functions with arbitrary arguments

Tags: c++

I want to create a C++ library where the user can pass a callback function with arbitrary combinations of arguments of three different types. The library would later, upon receiving some data, parse such data and call the callback with the appropriate arguments.

For instance:

```
class MyLibrary
{
public:
void registerCallback(std::vector<std::string> patterns, UNKNOWN_TYPE callback)
{
  this->patterns = patterns;
  this->callback = callback;
}

void parseData()
{
  for(unsigned int n = 0; n < patterns.size(); ++n)
  {
     DATA data = getDataForPattern(p);
     if(typeIdOfCallbackArgument(callback, n) == typeid(std::string))
       addToCallList(data.asString(), n);
     else if(typeIdOfCallbackArgument(callback, n) == typeid(float))
       addToCallList(data.asFloat(), n);
     else if(typeIdOfCallbackArgument(callback, n) == typeid(std::vector<float>)) 
       addToCallList(data.asVector, n);
  }
  callCallbackWithCallList();
}

private:
std::vector<std::string> patterns;
std::function<UNKNOWN_TYPE> callback;
type_info typeIdOfCallbackArgument(n);
template <typename T>
void addToCallList(T arg, unsigned int position)
{
 // do some magic to store arbitrary arguments in a callList
}
void callCallbackWithCallList()
{
 // do some magic to call callback() with the arguments stashed in the callList
}
};
```

and the user code could look like:

```
void myCallback(std::string propertyName, float value)
{
  setProperty(propertyName, value);
}

MyLibrary lib;
lib.registerCallback({"aproperty", "avalue"}, myCallback);
```

or

```
void anotherCallback(std::string propertyName, float value, std::vector<float> vec)
{
  setPropertyVector(propertyName, value, vec);
}

MyLibrary lib;
lib.registerCallback({"aproperty", "avalue", "avector"}, anotherCallback);
```

As I see it, there are three tasks:

1. "capture" the callback arguments when it is called
2. store the arguments for the callback as they are parsed
3. call the callback with such arguments

I *think* that by using a `template` for the `callback` argument of `registerCallback()`, I could use `typeid` at compile-time, and at runtime deduce from its output the argument types within `registerCallback()` by demangling the typeid.
I *think* I know how to do the function call by storing the callback as a `void*` and manually setting the registers and stack to pass the arguments to the function, but I'd really want to avoid that (I am on armv7, FWIW).

Are there any C++ features I could use to get this done in a safe and elegant way?

Note that:

- I explicitly want to avoid making the callback a C variadic function, in order to make the user code as straightforward as possible. That is: I would want the user code to look as similar as possible to the above.
- the above is a simplified case. In practice I would want to allow the user to register several callbacks for different `patterns` (i.e.: add more of those `lib.registerCallback()` lines with different arguments)

Comment: Why not just create an class interface with virtual `operator()` overloaded with all the types you need? Ex. inspect how `std::visit` is implemented for `std::variant`. Basically your `DATA` is a `std::variant` and the callback is the class that you pass to `std::visit`.

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks, but how would I go about calling the callback with the arbitrary number of arguments?